# how to fix the repeating div element?

Tags: angular

[image: code output][![

```js
quiz-data.component.html

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Quizcomp} from '../quizcomp'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz-data',
  templateUrl: './quiz-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-data.component.css']
})
export class QuizDataComponent implements OnInit {
  message:string[]=[]
  qcomp:Quizcomp[]=[]
  disable:any
  opt:string []=[]
  constructor() { }
  options:string

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  addmessage(Message){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.message.push(Message)
    }
    addoption(optTitle)
    {
      this.opt.push(optTitle)
      console.log(this.opt)
    }
    disableButton()
    {
      this.disable=false
    }

}
```

```html
quiz-data.component.html

<input #msg>
<button (click)="addmessage(msg.value)">Add question</button>
<div *ngIf="msg.value!==''">
  <div *ngFor="let mes of message; let i=index">
    {{message[i]}}<input #option><button (click)="addoption(option.value)">Add Option</button>
    <div *ngIf="option.value!==''">
      <div *ngFor="let qc of opt; let i=index">
        <div class="col-md-7"></div>
        <input type="radio">{{opt[i]}}
        <div *ngIf="i===3">
          <button disabled={{disable}} (click)="disableButton()">Save</button>

        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071BD.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/071BD.png)I am trying to build a simple quiz application to add question and options for that question, when i click on the add question button, it adds a question from the textbox,and displays the question along with the a text box for the add option button, it works fine for the first iteration. as i repeat the above procedure the previously added options are being displayed along with the new one

Comment: You're pushing new message into `this.message` array so you're seeing old data along with newly added data. If you want to have only latest message array then make `this.message = []` before pushing message in `addMessage()` method

Comment: Respected ma'am could you take a look at the screenshot i posted?

Comment: @Chaitanya moreover i am trying to display everything, if i do a this.message=[ ], the previously displayed questions will be cleared from the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Your `opt` array is used globally. So when adding question option you're added it to all question.

To achieve your goal you could transform `message` string array to object array containing two properties :

- `question` as string
- `opt` as string array containing option

With this approach you can iterate to display question title with its options.

```js
 

   

 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Quizcomp} from '../quizcomp'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quiz-data',
  templateUrl: './quiz-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quiz-data.component.css']
})
export class QuizDataComponent implements OnInit {
  message:any[]=[]
  qcomp:Quizcomp[]=[]
  disable:any
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  addmessage(message: string){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.message.push({
      question: message
      opt: []
    })
  }
  
  addoption(message, optTitle){
    message.opt.push(optTitle); 
  }
  
  disableButton(){
    this.disable=false
  }
}
```

```html
<input #msg>
<button (click)="addmessage(msg.value)">Add question</button>
<div *ngIf="message?.length">
  <div *ngFor="let mes of message; let i=index">
    {{mes.question}}<input #option><button (click)="addoption(mes, option.value)">Add Option</button>
    <div *ngIf="mes.opt?.length">
      <div *ngFor="let qc of mes.opt; let i=index">
        <div class="col-md-7"></div>
        <input type="radio">{{qc}}
        <div *ngIf="i===3">
          <button disabled={{disable}} (click)="disableButton()">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir, i tried your code, now the options are not being added

Comment: Sorry, my bad... change `msg.option` into `msg.opt` in template

Comment: still no luck sir!!

Comment: I've tested it and it works. Unless I have misunderstand your problem

Comment: no sir, it doesnt work for me, i am not able to add options, when i click on the add option button, no options are being added, PS sorry for the delayed response